# openssl is not finding any certificates

Tags: git, curl, ssl, certificates

When I use git or curl I get an error which may be related to certificates:

With git:

```
> git clone https://github.com/vim/vim.git
Cloning into 'vim'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/vim/vim.git/': error:140943E8:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:reason(1000)
```

With curl

```
> curl -v https://github.com
*   Trying 2001:8002:e42:f002::f5ff:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to github.com (2001:8002:e42:f002::f5ff) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS alert, close notify (512):
* error:140943E8:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:reason(1000)
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:140943E8:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:reason(1000)
```

If I try to see what is going on with openssl it doesn't seem to find any certificates:

```
> openssl s_client -ciphersuites TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 -connect github.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
139703172380480:error:140943E8:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:reason(1000):ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1543:SSL alert number 0
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 316 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

When I run the openssl command (above) on another machine it returns lots of info about certificates.

What can I do to diagnose/fix this problem?

I am using Fedora 31

Edit: Part of the output from "nmcli con show " is:

```
ipv6.method:                            auto
ipv6.dns:                               --
ipv6.dns-search:                        --
ipv6.dns-options:                       --
ipv6.dns-priority:                      0
ipv6.addresses:                         --
ipv6.gateway:                           --
ipv6.routes:                            --
ipv6.route-metric:                      -1
ipv6.route-table:                       0 (unspec)
ipv6.routing-rules:                     --
ipv6.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv6.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv6.never-default:                     no
ipv6.may-fail:                          yes
ipv6.ip6-privacy:                       -1 (unknown)
ipv6.addr-gen-mode:                     stable-privacy
ipv6.dhcp-duid:                         --
ipv6.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv6.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv6.token:                             --
```

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with any certificates; you're failing before the point the protocol would receive a certificate. **Check your DNS** -- I don't see any v6 address (AAAA) on any authoritative server for github.com, and the address your curl uses is assigned to Telstra in Australia (which is inconsistent with statements on github's own blog) and moreover doesn't route for me at all (from Eastern US).

Comment: According to http://www.whatsmydnsserver.com/ my DNS is 61.9.211.6. Do I somehow need to add that to my config? The output from "nmcli con show <name of my wired connection>" are shown in my edited post above.

Comment: Please try `curl -4 https://github.com/` to force IPv4 and see whether that changes something.

Comment: Using curl -4 as suggested by @Ned64 seems to work (it returns page content, not an error message). Does that mean I am using IPv4 instead of 6? What does that mean?

Comment: @John You may have an improperly set up IPv6 configuration. Please disable IPv6 completely on the computer and try the `git command`.  Disable by typing (as root): `echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/autoconf;
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/accept_ra;
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6` and let us know.

Comment: git clone now works after following @Ned64's instructions. Is this a permanent solution, or should I somehow fix IPv6?

Comment: @John Please try my permanent solution below and use it until you can find a fix. That may require more analysis and/or more wizardry than I can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apparently have an improperly set up IPv6 configuration.  As a workaround (not a fix but that may be complicated or impossible), please disable IPv6 completely on the computer and try the `git` command again.

Disable IPv6 by typing (as root):

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/autoconf
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/accept_ra
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
```

This will be effective until the next reboot.  In order to permanently disable IPv6 on your computer (until you undo it of course) you need to change configuration files.  How this is done is sadly very much dependent on your system.  Under Fedora this can probably done by editing the configuration file for your network which is located in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` and carries the name of your ethernet network, perhaps something like `ifcfg-enp4s2` if your network (see `ip a`) is called `enp4s2`.  Please add (or edit if it exists and is `=yes`) the line

```
IPV6INIT=no
```

This will be effective from the next restart of your network services (or reboot).

A different method that may or may not work on your system is to find the file `/etc/sysctl.conf` and add these lines (or adapt them if they exist):

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

and let us know.

Full disclosure: Lines to disable IPv6 copied from [How can I disable IPv6 in custom built embedded setup](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66574/how-can-i-disable-ipv6-in-custom-built-embedded-setup#answer-66578) .

Comment: @John Does the permanent solution work for you?  This depends on your setup.

Comment: Your first method (editing the relevant file under /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts) did not work, but the second method (editing /etc/sysctl.conf) did work. Thanks @Ned64

Comment: @John Great, thanks for the feedback. Since it worked please also upvote the question if you haven't done so yet. Thanks.